# Lubuntu: .desktop shortcut works on the desktop, but doesn't from the menu

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, lightdm

I've created a simple shortcut.desktop in my Lubuntu 13.04 /usr/share/applications:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=shockwave
Icon=/home/zane/Pictures/Evil Decepticons.png
Exec=/home/zane/Documents/Zane_Shockwave-RDP.sh
Terminal=true
MimeType=text/plain
Categories=GTK;WebBrowser;Network
```

The pointed sh contains just echo "it works".

If I double-click the .desktop it directly, the script runs and everything works as expected.

But if I click the menu entry from the desktop, I just get a "stuck", non-inputable Terminal.

Note: to workaround this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcmanfm/+bug/975152/comments/14 I've just "lxterminal" under PCManFM -> Prefernces -> Advanced, otherwise I can't run .sh at all.

Any ideas?

Edit I also tried these variant, but I always get the same result:

```
Exec=sh /home/zane/Documents/Zane_Shockwave-RDP.sh
Exec=lxterminal /home/zane/Documents/Zane_Shockwave-RDP.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [suggested here](http://sourceforge.net/p/lxde/bugs/597/), right-click and open the "Panel Settings"-dialog -> Advanced, then set "Terminal Emulator"="lxterminal" and now it works.